# Available data sets on basic income pilot studies?

Tags: dataset, data

I'm interested in exploring data relating to any UBI/basic income pilot studies that have been conducted but have been unable to find any so far?
thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the Open Data SE